# How to use reduce method within an array to convert multiple Json objects with common key into a single Json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a function within NodeJS which is returning Json Javascript object.

```
let rows = function1();
```

Here rows look like:

```
"rows": [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "PASS",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    }
]
```

Here, `rows` can have any number of Json objects for the same `Hostname` key:

```
"rows": [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "PASS",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name3",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
 ...
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name3",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    }
...
]
```

I want to modify the `rows array` such that all Javascript objects belonging to one `Hostname` are converted into a single Json object:

```
"rows": [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name1Status": "PASS",
    "name1Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name2Status": "FAIL",
    "name2Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name3Status": "FAIL",
    "name3Heading": "Not Applicable"
    ...
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name1Status": "FAIL",
    "name1Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name2Status": "FAIL",
    "name2Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name3Status": "FAIL",
    "name3Heading": "Not Applicable"
    ...
    }
]
```

I have written the following code but it overwrites all key value pairs and shows Json objects related to the last `Hostname` only

```
const res = rows.reduce((acc, rec) => {
    let result = { ...acc, [`Hostname`]: rec.Hostname,  [`${rec.name}Status`]: rec.Status, [`${rec.name}Heading`]: rec.Heading  }
    return result
}, [])

{
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name1Status": "FAIL",
    "name1Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name2Status": "FAIL",
    "name2Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name3Status": "FAIL",
    "name3Heading": "Not Applicable"
}
```

There could be some form of `for loop` outside of `res` so that it takes into account all distinct `Hostname` keys

Comment: Your desired output is not very well normalized (naming things like nameNUMBERStatus). Is there a specific reason it has to look like that, or is that something you came up with? Something like `{ "Hostname": "abc235", "rows": [...] }, { "Hostname", "def234", "rows": [...] }` would be much cleaner.

Comment: Using numbered properties like `name1Status` and `name2Status` and `name3Status` are hard for the consumer of this object to use.  they would literally have to manufacture property names and see if they exist.  Much better to offer an array of result objects that can be handled like any array of results.

Comment: Also, please use the proper terminology.  JSON is a text format.  These are Javascript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping and return the grouped values.

```js
var data = [{ Hostname: "abc123", name: "name1", Status: "PASS", Heading: "Not Applicable" }, { Hostname: "abc123", name: "name2", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" }, { Hostname: "abc235", name: "name1", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" }, { Hostname: "abc235", name: "name2", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" }],
    keys = ["Status", "Heading"],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { Hostname, name, ...o }) => {
        r[Hostname] = r[Hostname] || { Hostname };
        keys.forEach(k => r[Hostname][name + k] = o[k]);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSON elements](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)?

Anyway: this reducer should do it (using a helper method).

```js
const createEntry = (obj, value) => 
  ({...obj, [`${value.name}Status`]: value.Status, [`${value.name}Heading`]: value.Heading});

console.log(getRows()
  .reduce( (acc, value) => (
      {...acc, [value.Hostname]: createEntry(acc[value.Hostname], value)} )
   , {})
);

function getRows() {
  return [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "PASS",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name3",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name": "name3",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Actually as per the requirement, my output should same as given in the question. `{
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name1Status": "PASS",
    "name1Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name2Status": "FAIL",
    "name2Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name3Status": "FAIL",
    "name3Heading": "Not Applicable"
    ...
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "name1Status": "FAIL",
    "name1Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name2Status": "FAIL",
    "name2Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name3Status": "FAIL",
    "name3Heading": "Not Applicable"
    ...
    }`

Comment: @meallhour Modified